# How to use old Windows 10 C drive in new Windows 10 installation

Tags: windows-10, ssd

I had Windows 10 running on a 1TB SDD with loads of apps installed, and that PC's power supply crapped out. I had another, faster, more memory PC with 400GB SSD running linux and not much valuable data. I tried putting the 1TB SSD into the bigger PC, but it wouldn't boot, it kept getting into startup repair loop. The 1TB drive looks fine and is accessible from linux. But I also want to be able to use Windows apps installed on the 1TB drive. So I did a fresh install of both Zorin Linux and Windows 10 on the 400GB SSD, which is setup to dual boot. Sweet. But of course running apps installed on the 1TB SSD isn't good because they're not in the C:\Windows folder of the fresh installation, but rather in the D:\Windows folder (D: being the 1TB SSD). And naturally the registry is different. Is there a way to get the new installation on C: to use the Program Files, Program Data, and registry from D:? I don't really care about the apps on the new installation on C:, I only want the ones that were installed on D:

Comment: Try to add the old disk as a boot option with in a CMD that is run as Admin to use the command `bcdboot D:\Windows` .

Comment: Sidenote: Many of the Windows apps will run well under wine. Just mount the old SSD in Linux and open the app. For example, I prefer the Windows versions of 7-Zip to p7Zip (not kept updated), and IrfanView to native Linux pic editors (no, it's not as powerful as Gimp, but quick and user friendly).

Comment: @harrymc I'm not familiar with bcdboot, but reading about it sounds like it will overwrite the multi-boot menu that lets me select booting Windows or Linux. So I'm reluctant to try it unless you've got some confidence that it won't. Actually, it's on y todo list to install [refind](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) under linux, which replaces the grub2 boot menu with something much smarter.

Comment: In a UEFI computer it will just add another boot entry.

Comment: @harrymc Okay, I'll give it a try, thanks very much!

Comment: @harrymc Okay. It wasn't 100% smooth sailing, as it resulted in booting to a windows boot manager, which had an option to "boot another operating system" - and by that it meant "boot another Windows system"! But with some pressing of F12, I managed to get it to boot my Linux installation. And from there I installed rEFInd, which causes a reboot to display a nice menu of all available operating systems, not just Linux (or just Windows). So I'm happy, all of my apps, settings, and files are intact running Windows on the 1TB disk! Thanks very much!!

Comment: @sootsnoot - Instead of editing your question should submit an answer.  I went ahead and remove the answer from you quesiton.  You are encouraged to submit your own answer yourself, if harry wanted to submit an answer, they would have submitted it.

Answer (score 0):

I followed the advice in the comment from @harrymc. It wasn't 100% smooth sailing, as it resulted in booting to a Windows boot manager, which had an option to "boot another operating system" - and by that it meant "boot another Windows system"! But with some pressing of F12, I managed to get it to boot my Linux installation. And from there I installed rEFInd, which causes a reboot to display a nice menu of all available operating systems, not just Linux (or just Windows). So I'm happy, all of my apps, settings, and files are intact running Windows on the 1TB disk! Thanks very much!!

And I'm posting this as an answer on the advice of @ramhound, who deleted the answer I previously posted as an edit to the question (to give harrymc a chance to post the answer himself) because @ramhound thought that was the wrong way to deal with it, that harrymc would have posted the answer himself if he wanted to :-)